# Create ArrayList from contents of a textfile

Tags: java, android

I currently have an ArrayList hard coded within the app I am going to change.  What I'd like to do is replace the hard coded list with something that reads the list from a text file.  That way I can change the text file, without having to redo the code.

Currently it looks like this:

```
public ArrayList<BaseBean> createDummyMP3AudioList()
    {
        ContentBean bean = null;

        mContentList = new ArrayList<BaseBean>();   

        bean = new ContentBean();
        bean.isGroup = false;
        bean.setContentId("0");
        bean.setUrl("http://tx.whatson.com/icecast.php?i=kissnationallow.mp3");
        bean.setTitle("Kiss 100 FM MP3 Playback");
        mContentList.add(bean);         

        bean = new ContentBean();
        bean.isGroup = false;
        bean.setContentId("1");
        bean.setUrl("http://icy-e-04.sharp-stream.com/banburysound.mp3");
        bean.setTitle("Banbury FM MP3 Playback");
        mContentList.add(bean); 

        bean = new ContentBean();
        bean.isGroup = false;
        bean.setContentId("2");
        bean.setUrl("http://icecast.commedia.org.uk:8000/bangradio.mp3");
        bean.setTitle("Bang Radio 103.6 MP3 Playback");
        mContentList.add(bean);

        bean = new ContentBean();
        bean.isGroup = false;
        bean.setContentId("3");
        bean.setUrl("http://direct.sharp-stream.com/sunrise.mp3");
        bean.setTitle("Sunrise Radio Punjabi MP3 Playback");
        mContentList.add(bean);

        bean = new ContentBean();
        bean.isGroup = false;
        bean.setContentId("4");
        bean.setUrl("http://tx.sharp-stream.com/icecast.php?i=lincsfmdearne.mp3");
        bean.setTitle("Dearne FM MP3 Playback");
        mContentList.add(bean);

        return mContentList;
    }
```

How can I make it so that mContentList is actually read from a file, not from the list in the code?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you actually try any file reading API ? Have a look at [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/01/3-ways-to-read-files-using-java-nio/). If you face any issues while implementing, come back and edit your post :)

Comment: store all your urls in array or string. And use for loop on that list index. Add your code in that for loop.

Comment: Also it would help if you add the format in which data is laid out in your text file for others to address this